# OpenSSL on C writing garbage values after EOF

Tags: c, linux, debugging, openssl

So I am writing an archiver program to also encrypt-decrypt files sing block cipher. When decrpting from a archive file, and I have checked, in situations where the remaining btes of the fle before EOF is smaller than the read buffer some garbage values are written to the file. I am using OpenSSL's EVP API with C language. Any ideas what is wrong? You can find the code for AES 256 bit decryption below.

```
int TARIM_decrypt_aes256(FILE* infile, FILE* outfile, unsigned char* key, unsigned char* iv, unsigned long long int fileLoc, unsigned long int fileSize)
{
    if (infile == NULL || outfile == NULL || key == NULL || iv == NULL)
    {
        printf("(ERROR) decrypt_aes256: One/more parameters are NULL pointers\n");
        return 1;
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (ctx == NULL)
    {
        printf("(ERROR) decrypt_aes256: Failed to generate cipher context. OpenSSL: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        return 1;
    }
    EVP_CIPHER* cipher = EVP_CIPHER_fetch(NULL, "AES-256-CBC", NULL);
    if (cipher == NULL)
    {
        printf("(ERROR) decrypt_aes256: Failed to fetch cipher. OpenSSL: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        return 1;
    }

    // Explicitly Enable Padding
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 1);

    int num_read = 0;
    int block_size = EVP_CIPHER_block_size(cipher);
    int inLen = 1024;
    int outLen = inLen + block_size;
    unsigned char inbuffer[inLen], outbuffer[outLen]; // Allow space for additional block in outbuffer
    
    if (!EVP_CipherInit_ex2(ctx, cipher, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL))
    {
        printf("(ERROR) decrypt_aes256: Failed to Initiate Cipher. OpenSSL: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        
        EVP_CIPHER_free(cipher);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        return 1;
    }

    // Assert size of key and iv
    OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_key_length(ctx) == 32);
    OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_length(ctx) == 16);

    // Set key and iv
    if (!EVP_CipherInit_ex2(ctx, NULL, key, iv, 0, NULL))
    {
        printf("(ERROR) decrypt_aes256: Failed to set key and iv. OpenSSL: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        
        EVP_CIPHER_free(cipher);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        return 1;
    }

    // Seek to File Location
    fseek(infile, fileLoc, SEEK_SET);

    // Loop until bytes read
    unsigned long long int b_count = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        num_read = fread(inbuffer, sizeof(unsigned char), inLen, infile);
        b_count += num_read;

        if (!EVP_CipherUpdate(ctx, outbuffer, &outLen, inbuffer, num_read))
        {
            printf("(ERROR) decrypt_aes256: Failed to pass bytes to the cipher. OpenSSL: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
            
            EVP_CIPHER_free(cipher);
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
            return 1;
        }
        fwrite(outbuffer, sizeof(unsigned char), outLen, outfile);

        // EOF
        if (b_count >= fileSize || num_read < inLen)
        { break; }
    }

    // Cipher Final block with padding
    if (!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(ctx, outbuffer, &outLen))
    {
        printf("(ERROR) decrypt_aes256: Failed to pass bytes from final block to cipher. OpenSSL: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));

        EVP_CIPHER_free(cipher);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        return 1;
    }
    fwrite(outbuffer, sizeof(unsigned char), outLen, outfile);

    // Clean up
    EVP_CIPHER_free(cipher);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing the inLen variable to block_size but that gives me OpenSSL's bad decrypt error.

```
int inLen = block_size;
```

The Error comes out like this dring decryption:

```
(ERROR) decrypt_aes256: Failed to pass bytes from final block to cipher. OpenSSL: error:1C800064:Provider routines::bad decrypt
```

[Edit]
I did find a weird behavior of my program. So the program can encrypt files together into a single file. The files are not padded to differentiate to save space, instead I keep the record of the file size and figure out the start byte position in the code using their sizes and extract them. The only files that give me trouble when using inLen = block_size were the files who were a multiple for 'block_size' and only when they were clustered in a single file. Here is the code that figures out the start byte of a file:

```
// Get Relative Location
unsigned long long int relativeLoc = 0;
for (long long int itr = 0; itr < option_num; itr++) {
    if (block_size == 0 || fArray[itr].fsize == 0) {
        relativeLoc += fArray[itr].fsize;
    } else {
        // Adjust for padding
        relativeLoc += ((fArray[itr].fsize / block_size) + 1) * block_size;
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: You never check if `fread()` returns a short read or fails for any reason, and if that happens your decryption will go off the rails. You also need to reset `outlen()` to the proper buffer size before each call to `EVP_CipherUpdate()` or `EVP_CipherFinal()`. AES/CBC ciphertext from the default OpenSSL implementation will always be a multiple of the 16-byte block size, and the resulting full plaintext will be between 1 and 16 bytes *smaller* than the fill input ciphertext but IIRC until the last call to `EVP_CipherUpdate()` it will always return the same number of bytes as the input ciphertext.

Comment: Also IIRC, you have to pass incorrect values such as buffer size(s) to OpenSSL's AES/CBC decryption implementation.  If you use the wrong key, IV, or ciphertext, ISTR you'll still get plaintext out of the decryption with no errors reported.  It'll be *garbage*, but you'll still get it.  So unless you're doing some other integrity checking, for an archive only AES/CBC encryption isn't really sufficient.  AES/GCM will do integrity checking, but you need to preserve the 16-byte hash output by the encryption process, and you can *never* reuse an AES/GCM IV, so there's a bit more overhead.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: OP's use of `fread` return as `num_read` is correct and sufficient. You need not initialize `outlen` before `Update` or `Final`. When _encrypting_ in CBC every block-multiple Update returns same as input and Final returns one added block; when _decrypting_ first Update returns one block _less_, subsequent Updates same as input, and Final less than one block (possibly zero). If you decrypt wrong data/key/IV by mistake (not deliberate attack) there is good chance (but not certainty) PKCS5/7 padding detects it, although AEAD such as GCM is indeed _better_.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Just to be sure, I tried checking for any errors in `fread` and other things you recommended and it did nothing. I went on and checked key, iv and the buffer size during the runtime and nothing again.

Comment: I found an edge case while testing. I have added it to the post. It might help with understanding this bug more.